# Click a html tag, then invoke the smarty function

Tags: html, smarty

I have a Smarty templte.

in its php file I registered a block function:

```
function test1($args){
    $str="";
    for($i=0;$i<$args['times'];$i++){
        $str.="<font color='".$args['color']."' size='".$args['size']."'>".$args['con']."</font>"."<br>";
    }
    return $str;
}
// register block function
$smarty->registerPlugin('block' ,'hsp', 'test1');
```

and in the template:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>{$title}</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <button>
            Click me
        </button>

        {hsp times="1" size="5" color="green" con="hello,world"}
        {/hsp}


    </body>
</html>
```

I have two questions,

1. why I access the smarty file there gets two `hello,world`?

   `{hsp times="1" size="5" color="green" con="hello,world"}
   {/hsp}`
   <kbd>[image]</kbd>
   you see there is only 1 times.

2.I want to click the button, then I invoke the function, how to realize this?